# Entity Framework, modeling the scenario when one entity is used by several other entities

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

We have a model where a common entity is used by other entities(domains) and we want to create a relation between the entities in a generic way, if possible.

In the example, the Address is used by the Students and by the Schools and each can have one or several address and one address can belong only to one entity (not many to many relation)

```
 public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? RefId { get; set; }
    }

 public class School
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
    }
```

EF6 model first creates the following schema (without any additional configurations)

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.Addresses",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        RefId = c.Int(),
                        School_Id = c.Int(),
                        Student_Id = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Schools", t => t.School_Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Students", t => t.Student_Id)
                .Index(t => t.School_Id)
                .Index(t => t.Student_Id);
```

Essentially, adding foreign keys for each of the entities. This model works, however we are not sure if this is the best practice.

The problem we see, is that when adding other entities using Address, we need to continue adding the id of the new entity along withe the FK(for example Library - LibraryId). It breaks the abstraction of the concept of the address.

We tried to use an abstract ref id (RefId) and configure EF to use it as a FK key, but it created two FKs for the same table.

Another option is not to use any Navigation properties and to manually populate and handle the relation between the entities - practically not using ORM features.

As this seems to be a common scenario, is there a way to model it in a generic way?

Comment: The (anti) pattern name here is *polymorpic associations*. Using this as search term you'll find many post to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

A way would be to create an abstract class and inherit from that:

```
public abstract class AddressRef
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    // Navigational properties
    public virtual Address { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can inherit the above class when the address reference is required:

```
public class School : AddressRef
{
    // other properties
}

public class Student : AddressRef
{
    // other properties
}
```

This will allow you to manage the reference in only one place and use it in as many classes as you need.